# How to use different combining logic based on selected filters in Filterizer (http://yiotis.net/filterizr/)

Tags: jquery

[Filterizer](http://yiotis.net/filterizr/)  is a JQuery plugin to filter items and animate filtering using css transitions. It operates in 2 states, single and multi-filtering. In multifiltering, items are filtered using multiple filters. It either combine filters using OR or AND.

Can anyone tell how to use different combining logic based on selected filters using its API and/or options?

For example, there are 3 filters A, B, C:

- If A, B are selected, I want to combine them using OR
- If B, C are selected, I want to combine them using AND

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Combining of filters in Filterizer is a global setting and effects all filters.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to inform you that filterizer is not coded to have this kind of behavior. You can find alternatives to filterizer which may or may not have this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, filterizer doesn't provide such kind of customization. Filterizer will need major changes to provide this feature. Filterizer code is in ES6 and uses webpack for bundling.

Comment: Will you be so kind to let me know what code changes are needed?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar constraint in past. I had to change the architecture of filterizer. My work is linked below. You will need to build up further on top of my work as it is not exactly what you are looking for.
[modified filterizer bundle](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=86633880071101418566)

Comment: Welcome! That tinyupload link is a little scary. Can you put the GitHub link here, or upload the code directly to this answer?

Comment: @Alexandar Kimmel thanks a lot for providing your work.